# How to stop modem "stealing" local IP from router?

Tags: networking, router, ip, modem, subnet

I have a NetGear C6300 modem (TCP/IP 192.168.0.1) and NetGear R6700AX Wifi  router(TCP/IP 192.168.1.1) attached to it with an ethernet cable.

Every time I connect a device to the modem, it will get a local IPv4 IP from the modem (e.g. 192.168.**1**.3) at first. But around 5 minutes later the modem will "steal" the IP address from the router and assign it under its subnet(e.g. 192.168.**0**.3). I've tried:

1. Turning off the router's DHCP server and manually assigning a static IP to the Wifi modem.
2. In the modem's LAN setup, adding my device into Address reservation.

But the modem will still "steal" IP address from the router, I had chat NetGear, they will not tell me how or if there is even posible to enable bridge mode in router unless I pay for their preium tech support. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Which device would you enable bridge mode?  If you disabled DHCP on the second device, assigned it a static IP address, then only the first device should be assigning IP addresses.  You should [edit] your question as I am totally confused by your question.

Comment: I am also confused (I have 2 router and modem setup here). Make sure routers are connected to the modem LAN port to LAN port and that there is only ONE DHCP server. That is a start.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried to enable bridge mode on NetGear C6300 router. What I am trying to do is only using the NetGear R6700AX Wifi modem assign IP address, because it have QoS feature.

Comment: @John Router is connected to modem's Lan port. How can I have only 1 DHCP server? Right now disable either router or modem's DHCP server will make the network unusable.

Comment: I let the lead device be the DHCP server and then disable DHCP on other routers. If your Modem is a DHCP server then disable DHCP on your own routers. If your modem is in bridge mode then select a main router to be DHCP server.

Comment: Disable Router mode when you navigate to ADVANCED > Administration > Router Mode this process is described in the manual for the device that I downloaded from Netgear, but you need to enable Bridge mode on the NetGear R6700AX instead of the router. Enabling bridge mode on the modem doesn’t make logical sense.

Comment: @Ramhound Why? For me it makes perfect sense to use the modem just as a modem and let the router handle routing, DHCP etc.

Comment: How are the devices connected? Which port to which port, which devices provide WiFi etc.

Comment: @gronostaj - I guess you are right, i made that comment, after a really long frustrating day at work.  Instructions are likely the identical between the two devices anyways

Comment: @gronostaj Right now all the device are connected to NetGear R6700AX router via Wifi, and the router WAN port is connected to NetGear C6300 modem's LAN port with a ethernet cable. The modem is connected to ISP's Cable.

Comment: In that case what you've described isn't possible. The router separates networks. Devices in 192.168.1.* don't know that 192.168.0.* exists and that DHCP server can't be reached through the network boundary. Check if the modem is broadcasting WiFi with the same network name and password as the router. If that's the case devices can decide to switch to the modem's network if the signal is stronger.